# What does ® mean in the Chart Supplement (A/FD)?

Tags: airport, chart-supplement

What does the circled r: ® mean in the Chart Supplement (A/FD)? You can see it here to the left of SOCAL APP/DEP CON:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [Chart Supplement (formerly the A/FD) legend](http://aeronav.faa.gov/afd/10dec2015/SE_front_10dec2015.pdf):

> APP CON—Approach Control. The symbol ® indicates radar approach
>   control

And:

> DEP CON—Departure Control. The symbol  ®  indicates radar departure
>   control.

The FAA has different approach [facilities classifications](http://aspmhelp.faa.gov/index.php/OPSNET:_Facility_Classification), a TRACON has radar but others don't. So you should see this symbol when the approach/departure services are provided by a TRACON or other radar facility.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this legend](http://rowdy.msudenver.edu/~christib/wprof/aes180/AFDlegend.pdf) for the A/FD, the symbol indicates that the approach/departure control has radar. This means that ATC can more accurately locate, track, and provide guidance to pilots.