# What are the Radarless approach control services in the United States?

Tags: air-traffic-control

I was recently in Twin Falls, ID at KTWF. There is no radar for approach control services. All instrument approaches are full procedures and aircraft must report all requested fixes.

There is Salt Lake Center radar services at altitudes well above the usual approach and landing phase of flight for KTWF.

When I remarked to tower that is old school, they stated "last of two in the country."

What is the other?

Comment: "Radarless" = Procedural

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Twin Falls, ID
- Helena, MT

The Chart Supplement [shows if a facility has radar or not](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/23772/62). The entries for KTWF and KHLN show that there's no radar at the local TRACONs.

Comment: Did you go look through all of them until you found KHLN?

Comment: And since [TRACON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_traffic_control#Approach_and_terminal_control) refers to Terminal RAdar approach CONtrol, is a procedural approach control still a TRACON?

Comment: @dawg No, it just happens that I saw a post on pilotsofamerica.com about this recently :-) I only checked to confirm that the Chart Supplement agrees. There are a few other Google hits too, although this seems to be very obscure.